# PEP8 warning: continuation line missing indentation or outdented

Tags: python-3.x, pep8

I'm using `pycharm` where I really like the integration of PEP8 warnings which helps me to write neat python code.

usually when there are multiple return type for a `function` I use the return variables in multiple line like below,

```
raw_data,\
t_raw_data,\                      #warning in t_raw_data
words_info,\                      #warning in words_info
t_words_info,\                    #warning in t_words_info
tags_info,\                       #warning in tags_info
char_info,\                       #warning in char_info
t_char_info = preprocess(param)   #warning in t_char_info
```

Which gives me warning

```
PEP 8: continuation line missing indentation or outdented
```

So what is the good practice to receive multiple return values. What is the `pythonic` way. I came from `C++` background and I'm very new to this `pythonic` way.

Note: If I post the following code then there is no PEP8 warning but this seems pretty odd.

```
raw_data,\
    t_raw_data,\
    words_info,\
    t_words_info,\
    tags_info,\
    char_info,\
    t_char_info = preprocess(param)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Pythonic way -

```
(raw_data,
 t_raw_data,
 words_info,
 t_words_info,
 tags_info,
 char_info,
 t_char_info) = preprocess(param)
```

Comment: current warning on `t_raw_data` to `t_char_info` is `PEP 8: continuation line under-indented for visual indent`.

Comment: @Maruf Are you sure you gave one character space before every line from line no. 2? The variable names should start from the same indent. No pep8 warning in PyCharm with this code in my computer.