# PEP 8: E128 sometimes requires spaces and sometimes does not

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

This [post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50644045/11092636) suggests PEP 8: E128 requires spaces on the lines following the first one when they're all wrapped inside parentheses. However, with an `if` statement this doesn't seem to be the case. You can see that the first three lines do not have a warning and the following do because they do have a space:

[image]

Am I missing something? I am using Pycharm Community edition if that helps.

Code used:

```
def main(user_input):
    if (";" not in user_input
       and "DROP " not in user_input
       and "SELECT " not in user_input
        and "FROM " not in user_input
        and "DELETE " not in user_input
        and '"' not in user_input
        and ";" not in user_input
        and "=" not in user_input
        and ">" not in user_input
        and "<" not in user_input):
        pass
    else:
        exit()
```

EDIT: as there is a bit of confusion, this should be the correct indentation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOpip.png and this is the one Pycharm thinks is the correct one https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5oUr.png. Unless I'm mistaken (could be the case!).

Comment: The screenshot is helpful so in this case I'd say post code *in addition to* the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

PEP-8 *notes* that `if (` provides a natural 4-space indentation which allows a continuation to begin *after* the parenthesis:

```
if (";" not in user_input
    and "DROP " not in user_input
    ...
```

Your checker apparently does not care if you write

```
if (";" not in user_input
   and "DROP " not in user_input
   ...
```

instead, but, if you *do* use that indentation, you have to *continue* to use the same indentation. Your `FROM` line is the first line to deviate from that indentation.

---

This is common enough that the PEP even provides an anchor to link to [this paragraph](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements):

> When the conditional part of an `if`-statement is long enough to require
> that it be written across multiple lines, it's worth noting that the
> combination of a two character keyword (i.e. `if`), plus a single space,
> plus an opening parenthesis creates a natural 4-space indent for the
> subsequent lines of the multiline conditional. This can produce a
> visual conflict with the indented suite of code nested inside the
> `if`-statement, which would also naturally be indented to 4 spaces. This
> PEP takes no explicit position on how (or whether) to further visually
> distinguish such conditional lines from the nested suite inside the
> if-statement. Acceptable options in this situation include, but are
> not limited to:
>
> ```
> # No extra indentation.
> if (this_is_one_thing and
>     that_is_another_thing):
>     do_something()
>
> # Add a comment, which will provide some distinction in editors
> # supporting syntax highlighting.
> if (this_is_one_thing and
>     that_is_another_thing):
>     # Since both conditions are true, we can frobnicate.
>     do_something()
>
> # Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
> if (this_is_one_thing
>         and that_is_another_thing):
>     do_something()
> ```
>
> (Also see the discussion of whether to break before or after binary
> operators below.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why does https://i.imgur.com/FqsJjkc.png have warnings then?

Comment: Because of the indentation settings you chose.

Comment: Those are my indentation settings, I don't think I've ever been there, are they wrong? https://i.imgur.com/qwbgTDd.png

Comment: They are wrong *for you* if they highlight valid indentation as erroneous, that *you* want to use.

Comment: And since you're nitpicking on PEP8, PEP8 discourages the use ob tab characters. Also the interesting settings would be under "Wrapping and Braces".

Comment: Using 4 spaces instead of tabs solved most of my problems! Thank you @RichardNeumann

Answer (score 0):

The line with "FROM" is indented **1** space more than the line before. That's what's triggering the warning.

Comment: I know, but that's what supposedly should be done (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50644045/11092636). An extra space to "match the vertical alignment after the parenthesis".

Comment: No, and that's not what your link is saying.

Comment: On the link, there is a space on the second line, right? In my example there is not, and there is no warning. Although there should be one.

Comment: Either your checker *doesn't* care about that, or it is flexible and allows the `DROP` line to establish the "correct" indentation.

Comment: This should be the correct indentation:
https://i.imgur.com/FqsJjkc.png

Comment: And Pycharm thinks this one is correct: https://i.imgur.com/6DmejGi.png

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows I cannot reproduce this with my PyCharm indentation settings. Probably you configured your IDE so that it *does* detect your indentation as faulty.

Comment: Oh did I? I don't recall changing anything, but that would be reassuring meaning I've set up something locally wrongly.

Comment: Not changing the defaults is *choosing* the defaults. You're responsible for your IDE's settings, even if you (blindly) use its (potentially stupid) defaults.